# How set a GeneratedBy.Native into a CompositeId Fluent-NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I`m mapping a photo class, it can have many photos, so i decide create other class for control these photos.

So i have two primary key(PhotoCode, fkCode) and one of then is my foreign key.

```
   public class Photo : EntityBase
    {
        public virtual long PhotoCode { get; set; }
        public virtual long fkCode { get; set; }
        public virtual byte[] Photo { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as Photo;

            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

            return PhotoCode == other.PhotoCode &&
                    fkCode == other.fkCode;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = GetType().GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ PhotoCode.GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ fkCode.GetHashCode();

                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

So i want do set a Generator for my PhotoCode, setting this on my composite id.
This is my constructor on class map.

```
    public MapActivityPhoto()
    {
        Table("Photo");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(c => c.PhotoCode, "PhotoCode")
            .KeyProperty(c => c.fkCode, "fkCode");
        Map(c => c.Photo).Column("Photos");
     }
```

I know how to set this on Id, but how i supose set this on composite?

Example Id:

```
Id(i => i.Code).Column("Code").GeneratedBy.Native("GeneratorCode");
```

Comment: NHibernate does not support parts of the compositeId to be autogenerated ootb because this has lots of weired edge cases. I would strongly discourage the use of it too. However NHibernate has a feature NaturalId which could be handy for you.